# NUnit 3 console runner can't assert that collection is ordered

Tags: c#, travis-ci, nunit-console, nunit-3.0

I am running a CI build using Travis CI. I am running NUnit tests via the `nunit3-console.exe`.  I have several tests that attempt to assert that a collection is ordered:

```
[Test]
public void FeatsAreSorted()
{
    var result = controller.Generate() as JsonResult;
    dynamic data = result.Data;
    Assert.That(data.character.Ability.Feats, Is.Ordered.By("Name"));
}
```

When I run this test in Visual Studio, the test passes fine.  However, when I run the test via `nunit3-console.exe` in Travis CI, I get the following error:

```
1) Error : DNDGenSite.Tests.Unit.Controllers.CharacterControllerTests.GenerateSortsCharacterFeats
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : `NUnit.Framework.Assert.That<System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<CharacterGen.Common.Abilities.Feats.Feat,string>>(System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<CharacterGen.Common.Abilities.Feats.Feat,string>, NUnit.Framework.Constraints.IResolveConstraint)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: csharp
solution: DNDGenSite.sln
install:
  - nuget restore DNDGenSite.sln
  - nuget install NUnit.Runners -OutputDirectory testrunner
  - nuget install Chutzpah -OutputDirectory testrunner
script:
  - xbuild DNDGenSite.sln /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5.1" /p:Configuration=Release
  - mono ./testrunner/NUnit.Console.*/tools/nunit3-console.exe ./Tests/bin/Release/DNDGenSite.Tests.dll
  - mono ./testrunner/Chutzpah.*/tools/chutzpah.console.exe ./Tests/Unit/Scripts
```

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:** If I run the tests in the git bash, everything passes correctly, in both `Debug` and `Release` build modes.  So, there is something different about the environment in which Travis CI builds the console runner.

Comment: Check the version difference of the two compilers. Check the docs of `NUnit.Framework.Assert.That...` for protectedness and changes thereto. File a bug if necessary,

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Check the version differences (`compiler --version`) and see what changed. Check the documentation on how access specifier changed, as you might have an outdated library.

Comment: But that's what I'm wondering - it works just fine when Visual Studio runs it, so it should be the same compiled version between VS and when Travis CI compiles it.

Comment: Probably not, you're assuming (a) no bugs, and (b) the Travis compiler version to not be outdated, which it probably is

Comment: a) If there was a bug, it would show up when you run the test in visual studio, and that does not happen, b) even if the travis compiler version is out of date, the package restore is going to install the latest version of NUnit - which is what I am using.  So the Travis compiler really isn't manipulating the code that is throwing the error.  Perhaps I am missing something in your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found that asserting the order off of the `dynamic` object was causing the error in Travis.  If instead, I verified it equaled a different object and checked the properties on tat object, the test passes fine.